# How to unschedule previously scheduled local notifications after some time?

Tags: flutter, dart, localnotification

I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) library to schedule local notifications every 1 hour. It is working as expected but now, I need a way to start/ stop the notification schedule (say, at push of a button).

I could not find anything regarding canceling scheduled notification requests in the documentation.

Answer (score 14):

Cancelling/deleting a notification

```
// cancel the notification with id value of zero
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
// 0 is your notification id
```

Cancelling/deleting all notifications

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
```

And yes, this can cancel current and future notification. Just make sure correct notification id.

Answer (score 5):

In the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#cancellingdeleting-a-notification) it is given in Cancelling/deleting a notification

`await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);`

Comment: thank you for the reply but that is for canceling the notification with id value of zero

Comment: ok, you need to cancel on the basis of some other parameter ?

Comment: no all .cancel() does is remove the notification from the notification tray. I want to be able to stop future notifications that will pop up every hour

Comment: Are the notifications not stopping even after executing `await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();` ?

Comment: In the [API reference docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin-class.html) there is a [deleteNotificationChannel method](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/deleteNotificationChannel.html)

Comment: @rya were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @dev-aentgs The `deleteNotificaitonChannel` method is used to remove a [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). The `cancel` or `cancelAll` methods should remove any scheduled and/or current notifications

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
// Below will give you any unpresented/scheduled notifications
final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
for (var _pendingRequest in pendingNotificationRequests) {
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(_pendingRequest.id);
}
```

Here `_pendingRequest.id` will give you the required notification id to cancel the specific notification request.
This is tested in Android. Will update the status on iOS soon.

Comment: This is perfect if you don't want to delete the existing notification if it has already happened.

Answer (score 1):

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll(); //cancel future note
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests(); //restart note
```

And your notification will show again.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to cancel all notifications, then you have to do that using the following:**

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
```

**Also, if you want to cancel a specific notification, you can do this by using a specific ID of your notification:**

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);  // 0 is your notification id
```

**Where this notification ID came from ??**

While you are declaring your notification to show on your screen you have to add some data like given below:

```
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, // this is the notification id
        message.notification.title,
        message.notification.body,
        notificationDetails,
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
```

Here I am using Flutter Local Notification Plugin to show notifications!!!

Hope this will solve your problem.